# windows security log - failure reason startswith %%

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, security

Please help - do You have the list with descriptions of failure reasons eg. %%2313, %%2307... I've researched Net and nothing.. :(

Mainly I see it in ID 4625 in Windows security logs.

On http://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=4625 
we have only codes startswith 0xC... not %%....

Below we have log examle: http://forum.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/Topic87-168-1.aspx#bm450

Failure reason is value like %%.... - what does it mean and other like this?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Damiano

Comment: This one is driving me nuts too - I can't find documentation anywhere on what the FailureReason codes actually mean.

Answer (score 0):

In the 4625 Audit Failure record, look for the Status (It is of the form 0xc0). The individual values are documented here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4625

If your application is outputing values like 0XC000005E, the matching description would be "There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request."

Answer (score -1):

My take is that you won't know what those variables stand for if you don't have the source code. But why do you need to know though? You can have all text description in Event Viewer. Or if it's an exported file, ask whoever export it to export as full text.